# A grammatical problem

Tags: grammar

I ______ (complete) my homework by today.

a) will complete

b) will have completed

I think that the correct one should be b. However, I saw the sentence "the repair of XX will be completed by today" elsewhere. This makes me confused because I think that it should be "the repair of XX will have been completed by today.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Sometimes, multiple tenses can be correct.

Comment: I wouldn't use either. 'I will have completed my homework by this afternoon.'

Answer (score 1):

Currently I promise that I will complete my homework.

By tonight I will have completed my homework.

And just for fun;

My friend Sam gets his homework done by Fred. Sam will have had his homework done by the end of the day thanks to Fred.